# Limit of simultaneous possible connections to the server (TCP)

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, connection

I've written server and client modules in C++ on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 that allow multiple clients to send messages simultaneously to the server. If one of the clients writes "Hello": server responds with "world!", if one types "disconnect": the connection is broken and if client writes something else, server returns said message to the client.

I have following problem: I set with listen function in server.hpp to operate on maximum two simultaneous connections, but when I compile the program and run it I can launch more than two different clients and server doesn't complain. Why?

This is the code:

main.cpp:

```
#include "server.hpp"
#include "client.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    try
    {
        if (argc < 2)
        {
            std::cout << "Specify the mode: server OR client" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "server") == 0)
        {
            server();
        }
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "client") == 0)
        {
            client();
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error occured: " << ex.what();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Undefined error occured";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

server.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

void server()
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    const int PORT = 8888;
    
    std::cout << "Launched server\n";

    pid_t childPid;
    int socket_fd;

    if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to create a socket!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const int enable = 1;
    if (setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int))<0)
    {
        std::cout << "setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed!\n";
    }

    if (setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &enable, sizeof(int))<0)
    {
        std::cout << "setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT) failed!\n";
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(socket_fd, (sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to bind a socket!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(socket_fd, 2) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to listen\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in cliAddress;
    int cliAddress_size = sizeof(cliAddress);
    int client_fd;
    int cnt = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        std::cout << "Waiting for clients to connect...\n";
        std::cout.flush();
        if ((client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (sockaddr*)&cliAddress, (socklen_t*)&cliAddress_size)) == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to accept!\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        std::cout << "Connection accepted from: " << inet_ntoa(cliAddress.sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(cliAddress.sin_port) << '\n';

        std::cout << "Number of connected clients: " << ++cnt << "\n";

        if ((childPid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            close(socket_fd);
            while(1)
            {
                char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
                int bytes_received = read(client_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
                std::cout << "Received " << bytes_received << " bytes from the client wtih port " << ntohs(cliAddress.sin_port) << " " << buffer << "\n";

                if (strcmp(buffer, "Hello") == 0)
                {
                    auto msg = "World!";
                    std::cout << "Sending a response message...\n";
                    send(client_fd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
                } 
                else if (strcmp(buffer, "disconnect") == 0)
                {
                    auto msg = "Disconnecting client\n";
                    send(client_fd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
                    break;
                }
                else 
                {
                    std::cout << "Sending a response message...\n"; 
                    send(client_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                }
                
            }
                
            close(client_fd);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            close(client_fd);
        }
    }
}
```

client.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

void client()
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    const int PORT = 8888;

    std::cout << "Launched client\n";

    int client_fd;

    if ((client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to create a socket!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in cliAddress;
    cliAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    cliAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    cliAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    
    if ((connect(client_fd, (sockaddr*)&cliAddress, sizeof(cliAddress))) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to connect!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "What message do you want to send to the server? Or do you want to 'disconnect'?\n";
        std::string msg_temp;
        std::cin >> msg_temp;
        const char * msg = msg_temp.c_str();
    
        send(client_fd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);

        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
        int bytes_received = read(client_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        std::cout << "Received " << bytes_received << " bytes from the server: " << buffer << "\n";

        if (strcmp(msg, "disconnect") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    close(client_fd);
}
```

Makefile:

```
output: main.o
    g++ -std=c++20 main.o -o output

main.o: main.cpp client.hpp server.hpp
    g++ -std=c++20 -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o output
```

Comment: `listen()` does not do what you think it does. Its parameter does not specify how many active connections can exist at the same time, before any additional connections get rejected. The backlog parameter sets something different. If you need to limit the maximum number of concurrent connections you will need to implement this logic in the code, itself.

Comment: Do you have some tips how to implement it? I'm new to sockets and especially threads, because I think that it is what I need

Comment: @daryldxn You absolutely *do not need* threads.

Comment: While it's not necessary it is pretty common (and fairly harmless) to use two threads: one to listen for incoming connections, and one to service existing connections. Given that you're planning to limit it to two connections at a time, you *can* probably get away with using a thread for each connection as well (but a thread per connection model is *generally* a poor idea).

Comment: @JerryCoffin For just two connections at a time I'd probably go with one *process* per connection. Much simpler - no shared state, no locks, no "thread related complexity". Just `fork()` a new child after `accept()` and let it do its thing and just keep track of the number of current child processes. Keep it simple when possible.

Comment: The shown code `fork`s off a child process  for each new connection. The shown code fails to `wait()` for terminated processes. That, in itself, is a bug. Zombies will accumulate, and at some point you will no longer be able to `fork` any new processes. You must implement the appropriate logic that `wait`s for terminated processes, and implement a fine, delicate act of doing that simultaneously with `accept`ing new connections. Once that's done, you're now keeping track of all outstanding processes and connections, and can stop accepting new connections after two are already active. Success!

Answer (score 2):

A `listen()` backlog of 2 does not mean that only 2 clients can be connected. It means that a maximum of two clients can be in the (kernel) queue *waiting to connect*.

If you want to limit the number of simultaneously connected clients, you'll have to write your own code/logic to do that by keeping track of the currently connected clients and when someone disconnect and new ones connect.